# How to get first cell of selected row in datagrid wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

`I am trying to get id of selected user in datagrid,
the itemsource of datagrid is bound to an IEnumerable.

How to get the UserId when we select a row?
ViewModel:

```
public partial class UserSalaryViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private IEnumerable userssSalarires;
        public UserSalaryViewModel()
        {
            using AppDBContext db = new();
            UserssSalarires = db.Users.Join(db.UserSalaries, u => u.UserId, us => us.UserId, (u, us) => new
            {
                u.UserId,
                u.FirstName,
                u.FatherName,
                u.NIC,
                u.Salary,
                us.Pay,
                us.Month,
                us.PayDate,
                us.Finance,
                us.Rest
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserssSalarires}" />
```

Just Same to this one in windows form:

```
string cell = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

I tried a lot, I have searched a lot,
But, I couldn't find a solution for ananymos type.

Comment: Define a viewmodel for your user data. Bind selecteditem and it's userid of that. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Comment: Which type i should define for user_data, and then How to get UserId from that type. I have defined IEnumerable but I couldn't access UserId there.

Comment: You have an anonymous class there for each user. Create a class has the properties you need instead.